# tablesorter plugin sort only some of the columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tablesorter

I'm using [this plugin](http://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-sortable-table/) to sort my table. I'm trying to make only 3 of the columns (from 4) to be sortable how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using this [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), and not the original from tablesorter.com.

If that is the case, then simply add a "sorter-false" class name to the header in the table you don't want to sort.

```
<th class="sorter-false"></th>
```

What you're actually doing is setting the parser for the column; making it "false" just disables the sort.

There are [other methods](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html) to set a parser for or disable sorting in a column, but the class name is the easiest to remember.